# how to export csv file without #null in excel

Tags: excel, vba, spss

I need syntax in SPSS or excel to export data without #null values.

How can this be achieved?

I typically save as CSV and then in excel save as .xlsx. All missing values are then allocated a space which I accept as representing sysmis values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help in your code. Please update your original post with the code so someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, starting with SPSS 20, IBM decided that `#NULL!`is the Excel output of empty cells of numeric variables. You'll need to clean that manually in Excel (via Replace - `CTRL-H`), or write an Excel macro speed this up;

Alternatively, you could use an older version of SPSS, although I don't think they are commercially available anymore;
Or you could export as CSV and then import the CSV into Excel.

Comment: do you have any macro in excel to avoid #null during import a csv file

Comment: If you import CSV into Excel, there will not be any `#NULL!`. The `#NULL!` are related only to saving into Excel, but not into any other file formats (CSV, DAT, etc.)